# Hide navigatiobar

Tags: android, navigationbar, navigation-drawer

I'm trying to hide navigationbar on my project. Here is my code

```
  private void hideNavigationBar() {
        View decorView = getWindow().getDecorView();
        int uiOptions = View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
                | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
                | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN
                | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY;
        decorView.setSystemUiVisibility(uiOptions);
    }
```

I call this function on my onResume() function.
But when I'm opening popupwindow in my activity the navigationbar appears again. How can I solve my problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this out for full screen

```
public void fullScreenCall() {
    if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 11 && Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 19) { // lower api
        View v = this.getWindow().getDecorView();
        v.setSystemUiVisibility(View.GONE);
    } else if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 19) {
        //for new api versions.
        View decorView = getWindow().getDecorView();
        int uiOptions = View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY;
        decorView.setSystemUiVisibility(uiOptions);
    }
}
```

to only hide the navigation bar, is:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    final View decorView = getWindow().getDecorView();
    decorView.setOnSystemUiVisibilityChangeListener (new View.OnSystemUiVisibilityChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onSystemUiVisibilityChange(int visibility) {
            if ((visibility & View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN) == 0) {
                decorView.setSystemUiVisibility(
                        View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
                                | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                                | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                                | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY);
            }
        }
    });
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    final int uiOptions = View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION;
    final View decorView = getWindow().getDecorView();
    decorView.setSystemUiVisibility(uiOptions);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use it in `onWindowFocusChanged` callback.

```
@Override
    public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus) {
        super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus);
        if (hasFocus) {
            getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(
                    View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
                            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
                            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN
                            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

From android [doc](https://developer.android.com/training/system-ui/navigation.html)

> - With this approach, touching anywhere on the screen causes the navigation bar (and status bar) to reappear and remain visible. The
>     user interaction causes the flags to be be cleared.
> - Once the flags have been cleared, your app needs to reset them if you want to hide the bars again. See [Responding to UI Visibility Changes](https://developer.android.com/training/system-ui/visibility.html) for a discussion of how to listen for UI visibility changes so that your app can respond accordingly.